# Why isn't my custom macro showing up at template explorer?

Tags: resharper, resharper-plugins

I am trying to develop a macro for c# templates, but it simply doesn't work. I have tried reading the whole (incomplete) documentation, or find the source code of a macro to use as an example, but I failed on both.

I am able to build, install and debug the plugin. No errors, and both constructors and methods are called. But when I access the macros inside the templates explorer, nothing shows up there. I have also selected `All macros` from the options.

Here is my code

MyMacroDefinition.cs

```cs
[MacroDefinition("Subeta.Abp.ReSharper", LongDescription = "Long Description", Name = "My Name", Requirement = InstantiationRequirement.Instant, ShortDescription = "Short Description")]
public class MyMacroDefinition : SimpleMacroDefinition
{
    public MyMacroDefinition()
    {

    }
}
```

MyMacroImplementation.cs

```cs
[MacroImplementation(Definition = typeof(MyMacroDefinition), Requirement = InstantiationRequirement.Instant)]
public class MyMacroImplementation : SimpleMacroImplementation
{
    private IMacroParameterValueNew myArgument;

    public MyMacroImplementation([Optional] MacroParameterValueCollection arguments)
    {
        myArgument = arguments.OptionalFirstOrDefault();
    }

    public override string EvaluateQuickResult(IHotspotContext context)
    {
        return myArgument == null ? null : myArgument.GetValue().ToUpperInvariant();
    }
}
```

Subeta.Abp.ReSharper.nuspec

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Subeta.Abp.ReSharper</id>
    <title>Abp Support</title>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <authors>Subeta</authors>
    <owners>Subeta</owners>
    <summary>ReSharper support for ASP.NET Boilerplate framework</summary>
    <description>
      Required desc
    </description>
    <releaseNotes>
    </releaseNotes>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Wave" version="[11.0]" />
    </dependencies>
    <tags>aspnetboilerplate abp</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\Subeta.Abp.ReSharper.dll" target="DotFiles" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\Subeta.Abp.ReSharper.pdb" target="DotFiles" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the plugin get loaded by ReSharper at all? You need to make sure you have "zones" set up. Check this [Troubleshooting guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/Extensions/Troubleshooting.html) for reasons why it might not have installed correctly.

Comment: The guy who rocks on ReSharper's Github!!! Thank yooou! I found a working and updated extension of Live Templates / macros on github. I spend the day reading it and achieved a few advances, but it didn't work yet. I was able to display my macro in ReSharper's template editing page. I will try your suggestion as well so I can verify what is going on. This is much more complex than I expected, so I need some solid example, such as the repo I found. Thank you!!